# Array of data types

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7

For reasons I need to have something like this:

```
DT: array[0..3] of types = (string, integer, double, boolean);
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: No. What are the reasons for having an array of such types?

Comment: 1) make `record` 2) use array for you `record`

Comment: @Zam, please can you give me an example using record? Thanks!

Comment: Then make an enumeration and have an array of such enumeration values.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make an enum with your own type references... `type TMyType = (mtString, mtInteger, mtBoolean);`

Comment: You could declare an array type as `ATypes = array of PTypeInfo` (see TypInfo unit).

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Instead of asking how to implement some hack *X*, instead ask how to properly do *Y*. IOW, instead of this question, explain what you're actually trying to do and ask a question about how to do that instead.

Comment: None of these suggestions that you have received seem very great ideas to me. That's the problem with asking an XY question. If you ask about your problem rather than your solution I'm sure you will get more specific and contextual responses.

Comment: You could store values in  Variants (or TValue) records. Variants can contain all the named types (and more), and you can check which type they are. If you want to make a constraint, you can make an enum or an array of supported varTypes and check against that.

Comment: I am using this approach in a protection scheme, so I cannot give much details. But thank you all for the comments, I will try your tips and mr. Arnaud Bouchez answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if it would compile, the resulting `DT[]` array won't be usable for any profit.

You could only use something like

```
var v: DT[0]; // this will be a string variable
```

but it is clearly pointless, since you have in particular the ability to define custom types:

```
type
  TMyString = type string; 
...
 var
   v: TMyString;
```

So replace `TMyString` by `DT[0]` and you get what you expect.

If you expect to use `DT[]` e.g. with a loop, e.g. use `DT[i]`, I don't see any possible use of this syntax.

What I usually do on the other hand, is either:

- use `variant` variable to store any kind of value - I guess this is what you wanted to reinvent;
- use an enumerate meta-classes to initiate a given class on the fly.

First, `variant` values are pretty powerful:

```
var v: variant;
begin
  v := 1; // now v holds an integer
  ShowMessage(v); // will be converted to string before display
  if VarIsStr(v) then // false
    ShowMessage('string')
  else if VarIsNumeric(v) then // true
    ShowMessage('number');
  v := 'toto'; // now v holds a string
  ShowMessage(v);
  if VarIsStr(v) then // true
    ShowMessage('string')
  else if VarIsNumeric(v) then // false
    ShowMessage('number');
  v := true;   // now v holds a boolean
  if VarIsStr(v) then // false
    ShowMessage('string')
  else if VarIsNumeric(v) then // false
    ShowMessage('number')
  else if VarIsBool(v) then // true
    ShowMessage('boolean');  
...
```

And for metaclasses:

```
type
  TMyClassParent = class
  ...
  end;

  TMyClass1 = class(TMyClassParent)
  ...
  end;
  TMyClass2 = class(TMyClassParent)
  ...
  end;
  TMyClass3 = class(TMyClass1)
  ...
  end;

  // define the meta-class type
  TMyClassParentClass = class of TMyClassParent;
  // define an enumeration
  TMyClasses = (myclass1, myclass2, myclass3);

const
  MYCLASS_NAME: array[TMyClasses] of string = (
     'one', 'two', 'three');
  MYCLASS_CLASS: array[TMyClasses] of TMyClassParentClass = (
    TMyClass1, TMyClass2, TMyClass3);

var
  c: TMyClassParent;
  cc: TMyClasses;
begin
  for cc := low(cc) to high(cc) do
  begin
    writeln('Using ', MYCLASS_CLASS[cc].ClassName, ' for class ', MYCLASS_NAME[cc]);
    c := MYCLASS_CLASS[cc].Create;
    try
      // use Liskov's friendly c instance
    finally
      c.Free;  
    end;
  end;
end.
```

And if you follow properly Liskov's substitution principle, you may use `c: TMyClassParent` in an abstract manner, since the children wouldn't affect the expectations of the parent class behavior.

Comment: I used the `variant` approach for solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look in the system.pas and variants.pas in the Delphi source.

```
DT: array[0..3] of TVarType = (varString, varInteger, varDouble, varBoolean);
```

You can use VarType(value) to get the variant type.